# Need to create an action query to search for a string in the list of movies and produce the movie title and directors matching that string

Tags: mysql

I have set up two tables. one is movies with movies_id as primary key and another table directors where I have directors_id as primary key and movies_id as Foreign key. I need to create an action and form where I need to develop a SQL query to search for a string in the list of movies and produce the movie title and directors matching that string. I need to join info in two tables.

I tried LIKE  for instance I entered the below in my action but I am not getting any info. I was trying to list all movies with movie title "J".

```
  // Performing SQL query
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%J%';
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

I thought I will first find the info in one table before I can join two tables. But I am stuck! Any suggestions?

thanks,

Comment: Are you only searching movies and displaying their directors or searching for both movies and directors?

Comment: I am actually trying to join info from 2 tables.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

sql should be like this

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%J%' ";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

you have using single quotes to close the query in `$query` variable as well you `LIKE '%j%'` this will assign generate you invalid query so correct it with close the query with double quotes and like statement with single quotes. this will make you `$query` variable correct.

**UPDATE 2 :**

if you want to join with director table the query will be as follows

```
SELECT A.title, B.director_name 
FROM movie A, director B
WHERE A.id=B.movie_id AND A.title LIKE '%J%'
```

OR

```
SELECT A.title, B.director_name  
FROM movie A 
INNER JOIN director B ON A.id=B.movie_id
WHERE A.title LIKE '%J%'
```

Comment: @JimGarrison i had update the answer as you suggested. any update if required you can update my answer.

Comment: thanks! this works!! so I want to take the movie title from movies table and the corresponding director from directors table. i created directors table with directors id as primary key and movies title as foreign key. so if I want to join two tables and instead of 'j' i want to leave it blank so this way any letter is entered the corresponding movies titles and director will show up. so do i do an inner join? would you please help me? thanks

Comment: thanks a bunch! really appreciate it! instead of 'j' is there anyway i can leave it blank? so this way whatever alphabet the user enters in submit in form will list all the movies beginning with that alphabet? i tried '_' it did not work

Comment: you can remove the condition if you doesn't want. remove last line of WHERE clause if you don't want to get title like '%J%'

Comment: sorry but I got an error.My movies table is named movies and my directors table is named directors. the director's name column is named 'director' and movies name column is termed 'title'. Also is there any way I can leave the LIKE blank so this way whatever alphabet the user enters it lists all movies with the same first letter? thanks for your help!  here is the code I used  // Performing SQL query
$query = "SELECT A.title, B.director
FROM movies A
INNER directors B ON A.id=B.movies_id
WHERE A.title LIKE '%J%' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: change table names and field names in the query according to your original tables and fields

Comment: here is the code i used // Performing SQL query
$query = "SELECT A.title, B.director
FROM movies A
INNER directors B ON A.id=B.movies_id
WHERE A.title LIKE '%J%' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: sorry a newbie! bear with me! so what is wrong with the below code? what is the code to use if i want to list all movie titles based on the alphabet the user submits in the submit input? // Performing SQL query
$query = "SELECT A.title, B.director
FROM movies A
INNER directors B ON A.id=B.movies_id
WHERE A.title LIKE '%J%' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: sorry i had wirte only `INNER` it will be `INNER JOIN` i have updated it. please see.